# Accessing PHP variables in CSS file

Tags: php, css

I would like to dynamically set styling of items based on the scenario in the browser. I have a set of buttons set up in HTML, content populated through PHP.

On clicking a button, a modal appears with a set of buttons in it. The number of buttons populated in the modal changes depending on the button clicked. Therefore I need dynamic css, so the positioning of the buttons adapts to the number of buttons. This way I avoid scrolling and the UI looks better, which leads to an overall better User Experience.

I used the process described in following url to set up a css stylesheet with .php extension.
Then I connected the stylesheet to the application and set some variables in php which, if they are changed, change the css styling.

https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

My stylesheet is connected to the page, and the PHP variables are correctly set up to communicate with the css code in it. 
Now the question is: how can I access these PHP variables in the CSS stylesheet through PHP code executed on my page?

A simple example:

My CSS Stylesheet with PHP extension (stylecss.php)

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); 

    $vcaModal_itemWidth = 25;
    $vcaModal_itemHeight = 50;

?>

.vcaMenu_redesign_item{
    width: <?php echo $vcaModal_itemWidth . "%"; ?>;
    height: <?php echo $vcaModal_itemHeight  . "%"; ?>;
}
```

In my Page (simplified example):

```
if($num_items > 10){

    HOW DO I CHANGE $vcaModal_itemWidth TO 50, so the percentage changes dynamically?

    <button class="vcaMenu_redesign_item"></button>

}
```

If the number of retrieved items is larger than 10 change the width of my generated html element accordingly.. How do I access/ change a variable in my CSS stylesheet with .php extension with PHP code on my page?

Comment: It sounds like your modal has a fixed size? Why not just use a more adaptable CSS layout which can cope with changes to the size of the content? This is generally not such a difficult thing to define, without restoring to this approach (think responsive design techniques, flexbox, or even just using proportional measures e.g. % for size etc etc). What you're describing is not something people commonly do or find necessary. Even in the worst case, you could use client-side JavaScript to modify the appearance in response to changes.

Comment: Are you using like this:
<?php    $vcaModal_itemWidth = 25;
              $vcaModal_itemHeight = 50; ?>

        <style>
            .vcaMenu_redesign_item {
                width: <?php echo $vcaModal_itemWidth . "%"; ?>;
                height: <?php echo $vcaModal_itemHeight  . "%"; ?>;
            }
        </style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current set up, you cannot effect changes to your CSS file by modifying the variables inside of PHP "live" - that's not how PHP works. At best, you'd need some sort of state involved to store the values, and then re-render your CSS file from the server.

To be honest, this sounds much more of a job for the client than the server. Why not investigate using Javascript to manipulate CSS, instead of PHP?